# I am looking for a way to edit GPO using command line

Tags: service, command-line, automation, registry, gpo

I am configuring two Windows Server 2008 installations to harden them against attack, and there are tons of services, policies, security options, registry settings, to work on.
I'm looking at powershell, batch files, but no luck though (I was hoping to "automate the commands" without going through the tiring process).

I would be glad if anyone could advise me on this.

Comment: Well actually, if I were to work on the 1st server manually, and save the configs on to the .inf file. It will work somehow on the 2nd server but I am wondering if there are any other alternatives, without working on it the first round. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have enough knowledge in the basic Powershell. You can to use `wmi` objects with Powershell to achieve your tasks.

Take a look at this handy tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730935.aspx

I would also suggest you to use Server Core if you really want to harden servers against attack.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, posted here on StackOverflow, looked around more and I found a way of modifying GPO's directly (my implementation via Powershell). Its not pretty, but it IS functional for programmatically modifying GPO's: [Using Powershell to edit/modify a GPO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530326/using-powershell-to-edit-modify-a-gpo)